# Excel: How to create drop down list and extract data based on selection?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a master list in another workbook, and in my second workbook, I can enter name in first column. What I want is, create a drop down list for 2nd and 3rd column, where in the picture I upload, the 2nd column can choose the "race", and 3rd column can only choose whatever "classes" available to corresponding "race" chose in 2nd column, after select both the columns, the "village" column will be extracted from the master list workbook, and the number of "active player number" in master list will be increased. How do I do that?

**ClassList:**
[image]

**Entry:**
[image: image2]

Comment: How `Village` is related in both sheets?

Answer (score 0):

For `Race` and `Class` you can do Cascaded Drop Down List.

First write Race in a column without blank

```
Race
Human
Goblin
Orc
Elf
```

Then for each cell in Race create a new column with its elements

```
 Human  Goblin  Orc     Elf
Warrior Warrior Warrior Warrior
Wizard  Rogue   Hunter  Archer
Hunter  Archer  Druid   Rogue
Rogue   Shaman  Shaman  Priest
Priest                  Wizard
                        Druid
```

1- Select all cells under Human: `Warrior`-->`Priest` and Define Name `Human`
 2- Select all cells under Goblin: `Warrior`-->`Shaman` and Define Name `Goblin`
 3- do the same for the cells under Orc and Elf
 4- In the entry sheet:

- Under Race column B2 (you can select several cells) set a Drop Down List, Source is the cells under Race in the first column (without Race)
- Under Class column C2 set a Drop Down List, Source =Indirect(B2) without `$` remove it
  Whatever you choose in B2 will define the new list in C2

For `Village` if there is any relation (No or Name) with the master sheet, you can use Index / Match or Vlookup (you have to show an example of Master sheet or more explanation)
Also more information needed to increase the Number of Active Player